# How to manage persistant caching in Office 365 for Windows and Mac OS?

Tags: macos, caching, office365api, office365-apps, office365-restapi

I am new in Office 365 Add-ins. I want to know about caching. I am working on a Add-In using Office.js. I want to manage caching.

Scienario:

1- Add-In will get data from server once in a day. Data can be in MBs(i.e 5 MB).

2- It should store somewhere. So, user can use it even there is no internet connection.

Is there any internal caching mechanism provide by Office APIs?

I was also thinking to store in File. Is it possible to create and manage File using Office Add-ins in Windows and Mac?(I am just curious about File permission in Mac)

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You need to read through the following resource: [Persisting add-in state and settings](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings). Depend on the Office application you are writing your add-in for you would need to use different objects or approaches (for example use HTML5 web storage, etc.)